# How to use pytest correctly

Tags: python, testing, github, continuous-integration, pytest

I'm building my first python package.
I noticed an automatic test of the code made directly into GitHub by pytest
I surfed for good and clear explanations but I can't figure out myself
Is there any way you can help me?

The dir structure:

```
-> deezepy:
       |
       -> __init__.py
       -> client.py
       -> types.py

-> tests/
       currently empty
```

what should I put in my test directory? the two files:

client.py -> https://hastebin.com/yoyemirula.py

types.py -> https://hastebin.com/amafegilic.rb

I'm very glad about anybody that can help me using these tools for the first time, thanks!

Comment: You have to write some tests first.

Comment: @hoefling yeah, but how?

Comment: Check out [Create your first test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#create-your-first-test)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `pytest` to run on each git push, you should consider a **[GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions)** like: [Python Pytest GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/python-pytest-github-action).

Follow "[**Automate Python Testing With GitHub Actions**](https://medium.com/swlh/automate-python-testing-with-github-actions-7926b5d8a865)" from [**Rupert Thomas**](https://twitter.com/rupertthomas) for a more manual example (he does not use that action, but explicitely all the steps required to run pytest on your code).

[image: https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*mgJ8S_Chqt755Aw5MSSHaw.jpeg]